# How to get Certificate running Kubernetes cert-manager

Tags: digital-ocean, cert-manager

I am trying to setup TLS in kubernetes(DigitalOcean), using cert-manager.

Using Let's Encrypt and certbot on a server machine is well described, but when running in Kubernetes I can not find any information.

I found [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/networking/load-balancers/how-to/lets-encrypt/) but how can I use the certificate in cert-manager on Kubernetes cert-manager *ClusterIssuer*:

```
apiVersion: certmanager.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
 name: letsencrypt-staging
spec:
 acme:
   # The ACME server URL
   server: https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
   # Email address used for ACME registration
   email: your_email_address_here
   # Name of a secret used to store the ACME account private key
   privateKeySecretRef:
     name: letsencrypt-staging
   # Enable the HTTP-01 challenge provider
   http01: {}
```

I dont have any email registret?

Comment: Is this what you need: https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use any temp mail service but at expiring date of certificate you will not get noticed.

you can use any of you email gmail or anything if you want to setup certificate in Kubernetes using ingress and cert-manager you can follow this link by Digital ocean: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nginx-ingress-with-cert-manager-on-digitalocean-kubernetes